# Why does my chart created with Easychart not display a chart if number of points are more than 1000?

Tags: 7, javascript, charts, modal-dialogs

I installed [Easychart](https://www.drupal.org/project/easychart) module 7.x-3.7 in my Drupal 7.51 site. I'm using Highcharts 4.2.7 in libraries 7.x-2.3.

In the example contenttype `easychart_ex`, I tried uploading a `data.csv` file with number points more than 1000. When trying to do so, my chart display portion displays "no data to display" before and after save/view. Here is a screenprint of it:

[image]

However if the same file has number of points less than or equal to 1000, it displays the chart without problem. Here is a screenprint of it:

[image]
[image]

My question: Is there any configuration settings I need to review to display all the points without any restriction?

However, when I chose scatter plot, it displayed all the points as in this screenprint.

[image]

If I am able to do the same thing as in scatter plot with a reduced dot size and line joining dots, it will be great!

Comment: Curiosity: have you tried to save the node, and then view it again (in that scenario, how does the chart look like? does it still say "no data to display"?

Comment: Yes. In line chart, it shows "no data to display". In scatter plot, it shows fine.

Comment: hm, interesting ... can you edit your question to include that extra information. Ideally with a screenprint that shows the workig variation? FYI: I start to think that this is some chart configurarion option (though I don't know yet how to configure that).

Comment: Updated question!

Comment: I feel like helpless. Is there anyone who can help me with this issue please.